# Почему marker-mid не отображается?

Tags: html5, svg

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" viewBox='0 0 200 200'>
  <defs>
    <marker id='MarkerArrow'refX='0' refY='10' markerUnits='userSpaceOnUse' orient='auto' markerWidth='20' markerHeight='20'>
        <polyline id="markerPoly1" points="0,0 20,10 0,20 2,10" fill="crimson" />
    </marker>
      <marker id="MarkerCircle" refX="0" refY="5"
           markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="crimson"  />
      </marker>
      <marker id='MarkerCircleMid' markerWidth='30' markerHeight='30' refX='10' refY='0' orient='auto' markerUnits='userSpaceOnUse' >
          <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
  </defs>
  <line x1='0' y1='100' x2='100' y2='100' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='5' style="marker-start: url(#MarkerCircle); marker-mid: url(#MarkerCircleMid); marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow)";  />  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`marker-mid` появляется  только на изломах линии, а у вас была прямая линия

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" viewBox='0 0 200 200'>
  <defs>
    <marker id='MarkerArrow'refX='0' refY='10' markerUnits='userSpaceOnUse' orient='auto' markerWidth='20' markerHeight='20'>
        <polyline id="markerPoly1" points="0,0 20,10 0,20 2,10" fill="crimson" />
    </marker>
      <marker id="MarkerCircle" refX="0" refY="5"
           markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="crimson"  />
      </marker>
      <marker id='MarkerCircleMid' markerWidth='10' markerHeight='10' refX='2' refY='2' orient='auto' markerUnits='userSpaceOnUse' >
          <circle r="4" cx="5" cy="5" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
  
 <polyline   points=" 50,80 140,80 80,100 180,100 160,85 160,150 "  fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='5' style="marker-start: url(#MarkerCircle); marker-mid: url(#MarkerCircleMid); marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow)";  />  
</svg>
```

Comment: у marker  есть свой viewBox это как-нибудь влияет при выводе polyline ?

Comment: @Leks у маркера нет viewBox, зато есть  `markerWidth=` Это ширина прямоугольника, где распологается маркер, что выйдет за эти рамки, будет обрезано На `polyline` маркер никак не влияет, он к ней просто присоединяется

Comment: почему в таблице Атрибуты маркеров https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=855 указан  ?

Comment: @Leks Ну значит я уже начинаю что-то забывать, но всё равно в этом случае масштабируется только маркер, линия остается без изменения

Comment: что будет если в шапке viewBox и у маркера viewBox ?

Comment: @Leks у маркера `viewBox` будет масштабировать только маркер внутри ограничивающего прямоугольника  `markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10"` а внешний `viewBox` будет изменять всю картинку в целом